# Recuperate maximum bipartite matching from maxFlowFordFulkerson in R

Tags: r, graph-theory, mathematical-optimization, bipartite, ford-fulkerson

I want to find the maximum bipartite matching, so I'll use Flow Ford Fulkerson's algorithm, as [explained here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/).

But when I implement the function, I only get the value of the maximum flow, but what interests me is the flow itself, so that I can find the matching.

Can anybody help me?

I used the function `maxFlowFordFulkerson` in R.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that using only the output of the function you've found. Besides the value of the maximum flow, it does also provide a minimum cut, which provides some additional information but still not what you're looking for.

Using the example from the page you refer to (reproduced below for ease of reference):

[image]

```r
> library("optrees")
> vertices <- 1:14
> edges <- matrix(c(1,2,1, 1,3,1, 1,4,1, 1,5,1, 1,6,1, 1,7,1, 2,9,1, 2,10,1, 4,8,1, 4,11,1, 5,10,1, 6,11,1, 7,13,1, 8,14,1, 9,14,1, 10,14,1, 11,14,1, 12,14,1, 13,14,1), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3)
> maxFlowFordFulkerson(vertices, edges, source.node = 1, sink.node = 14)
$s.cut
[1] 1 3

$t.cut
 [1]  2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14

$max.flow
[1] 5
```

Here, the vertices in the two partitions are 2:7 and 8:13 respectively, so this tells us that vertex 3, i.e. the second vertex from the top in the left partition, remains unmatched, but other than that it tells you nothing about the matching.

If you want to stick to `igraph`, you can use [`maximum.bipartite.matching`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/igraph/versions/0.7.1/topics/graph.matching) to get what you want. As this one operates on bipartite graphs directly, we don't have to mess with the auxiliary source/sink vertices at all. With the example from above:

```r
> library("igraph")
> A <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0,0,0, 0,0,1,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1), byrow = T, ncol = 6)
> g <- graph.incidence(A)
> maximum.bipartite.matching(g)
$matching_size
[1] 5

$matching_weight
[1] 5

$matching
 [1]  8 NA  7  9 10 12  3  1  4  5 NA  6
```

Here, the left partition is represented by 1:6, and the right partition by 7:12. From `$matching`, we read that the 6 vertices in the left partition are matched with 8, nothing, 7, 9, 10, and 12 respectively.